# Creating a custom binding in WCF from an existing nettcpbinding

Tags: wcf-security, nettcpbinding

Can anyone tell me how to create a custom binding that reproduces the exact same behavior from the following  in WCF?

```
<netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureTcp" >
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
```

All of the googled solutions that I've found don't seem to be working for one reason or another. I've found a lot of solutions regarding httpTransport, but very few regarding nettcptransport.

The above  configuration is currently working, but I need to modify the maxClockSkew, and the only way to accomplish this is with a custom binding.

Thanks in advance,
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's what I was able to come up with. They key was the authenticationMode in the secureConversationBoostrap section:

```
<binding name="CustomSecureTcp">
    <transactionFlow  />
    <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation"requireSecurityContextCancellation="true">
      <secureConversationBootstrap
        authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport">
      </secureConversationBootstrap>
    </security>
    <binaryMessageEncoding/>
    <sslStreamSecurity requireClientCertificate="false" />
    <tcpTransport/>
  </binding>
 </customBinding>
```

EDIT: I'm pretty sure that the 'transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"' was unnecessary